# Is it possible to undo changes in a particular file in a commit in Git Web UI?

Tags: git, github

I know it is possible to make changes in a file in **GitHub Web UI**. But if I want to revert changes in a particular file in a commit, is it possible to do it in the Web UI of GitHub?

Answer (score -2):

Not sure of GitHub Web UI. But you can do this via command line.

```
git checkout abcde file/to/restore
```

Here `abcde` is commit hash.

**Edit: This change has been made based on the OP comment.**

You can do it from web UI too. Here are the steps to do it.

- Go to a suitable repository and click history.
- Choose the commit you wish to revert from the commit history list.
- Right click on the commit and choose to revert this commit.

**Note:** *When you revert multiple commits, it's best to revert in order from newest to oldest. If you revert commits in a different order, you may see merge conflicts.*

Comment: Yes, I know this. But I want to do this in the Web UI.

Comment: @Shravan40 OP wants to revert changes **to a file**, not revert commits.

Comment: @RomainValeri: Oops, I missed it totally. Thanks for pointing it out.